# File copy over network

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to copy files from a windows 7 machine on the network to my local machine which is also a windows 7. Both the file systems are NTFS. I am able to copy files of size around 2 GB. But when I try to copy files of around 7-10 GB, file copy doesn't initiate on my local machine. Is there some size limitation on file copy over the network or Windows 7?

Comment: There is no size limitation for copying (NTFS maximum file size is 16EB-16TB depending on implementation [source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)], and of course your free disk space)

Answer (score 1):

there is no limitation as far as I know .

This could be because of :
  - intentional network fragmentation on the network (so it limits the maximum transfer file , and keeping the network reservers)
  -package loss over the network .

To trouble shoot it you might want to use xcopy from cmd or Copy-Item (cp) from powershell ,
this will give you more details about what goes wrong.

Regards,
Alex H